Two open contractible subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are not homeomorphic but are polynomial preimage of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$
About  2 decades ago I heared from some one that there are infinitely many open  contractible  subsets of  space  mutually non homeomorphic  to each other. I  confess that I  do not remember the  details of  construction but I remember the  construction was not  so  routine(If I am not mistaken the  method was based on infinitness of the  set of prime numbers..)
But can  such examples be  constructed in an algebraic and semialgebraic manner?

In particular are there two polynomials  $H,G: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$  and  two open sets  $U,V$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $H^{-1}(U)$  and  $G^{-1}(V)$ are  non homeomorphic contractible  sets?


U and V then should be open intervals, wlog  (0,1) no ?

@PietroMajer   Yes we may assume $U=V=(0,1)$

@PietroMajer  BTW  no  because bounded intervals  are  not  algebraic  equivalent to unbounded  intervals  for  example $(0,1)$ is  not  algebraic  equivalent  to  some thing $(0,\infty)$. So  I prefer the original  formulation: arbitrary open  sets $U,V$
